# Is there a way to extract from Redshift Via SSIS using Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, amazon-redshift, ssis-2012

I am currently migrating a sql server db to redshift and have a downstream ETL process which uses variable sql scripts in SSIS to extract data from various schemas and loads them back to a sql server.

I am currently trying to refactor the SSIS component to also use variables but this does not seem to be an option for ODBC connections.

Do anyone know if there is a way in which I can achive this?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, but do you know about SSIS _property expressions_? https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/working-with-property-expressions-in-sql-server-integration-services/ This is a way of setting most parts of a task dynamically

Comment: Or do you mean using _parameters_ against your ODBC source?

Comment: We have dynamic scripts which run as part of a package and iterate through a series of schemas. e.g. iteration1 select a,b,c,d from alpha.table iteration2: select a,b,c,d from beta.table. From what I can see paramaterised variables are only available in OLE-DB connections.

Comment: Parameters won't help you switch schemas but property expressions will. I don't have SSIS open now to check but first you need to create a variable, then use an expression to dynamically populate that variable to build your SQL statement. Then you can use that variable as your source SQL _or_ you can use a property expression to set the source SQL to that expression.

Comment: Thanks for that. That is exactly what I am doing in fact. The problem I am having is that I am unable to maintain this process after our source migrates from SQL server to redshift. Have you any experience using expressions from a redshift source?

Comment: No but the source shouldn't matter. You are just pre generating a SQL query as a string that run against a source (whatever that source may be). I don't know what you mean by "I am unable to maintain this process after our source migrates from SQL server to redshift." If you get an error please post it. If you don't get an error please edit your question to explain a little better. What is the source and what is the target and what issue are you having?

Comment: The crux of the issue related to switching drivers from OLE-DB to ODBC. Amazon Redshift does not support OLE-DB but does have a ODBC driver. The implementation for Parameterised variables differs between the two however the link you provided above set me straight.

Comment: When drivers won't support parameters (or just throw weird errors or don't work properly), the workaround is dynamically generated SQL. Glad I could help. If you have time could you add an answer for anyone else looking for the same problem